# Does PyDev's type hinting support generic types?

Tags: python, pydev, type-hinting

I'd like to say something like:

```
'''@type foo: list<Bar>'''
```

and then have it know that when I access an element of `foo`, the resulting value is of type `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PyDev still does not support that... (this is a shortcoming on PyDev itself and it's already reported: see: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/147)

Once the basic type inference can work with it, then type-hinting should have that support enable too...

Answer (score 0):

Two years later: the correct answer is now to use Python's type annotations and MyPy :)